# primeng p-table show first and last page in paginator

Tags: angular, primeng

<p-table [paginator]="true"> only shows 5 pages by default. I would like to bring it to a view where the first and last page are also always visible. e.g. 1...4,5,6,7...13.
[image]

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support provided by the primeNg to create a design as per your requirement but It provides custom pagination so you can implement your own design and logic.

In the below code, you can add your custom code inside the template paginatorleft, paginatorright, and paginatordropdownitem as per your requirement.

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [first]="first">
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor=" let col of columns">
            {{col.header}}
        </th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            {{rowData[col.field]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="paginatorleft" let-state>
    {{state.first}}
    <button type="button" pButton icon="pi-refresh"></button>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="paginatorright">
    <button type="button" pButton icon="pi-cloud-upload"></button>
</ng-template>
<ng-template let-item pTemplate="paginatordropdownitem">
    {{item.value}} - per page
</ng-template>
```